# Negative lookbehind alternative

Tags: regex, go

I have a string

`centenary`

I'd like to match `ten` only when it is not preceded by `cen`.

So far I have this regex:

`(([^c][^e][^n])|^)ten`

That returns `true` in the following cases `tenary`, `blahtenary` and false for `ctenary`, `cetenary`, `centanary`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    txt := "ctenary"
    rx := `(([^c][^e][^n])|^)ten`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(rx)
    m := re.MatchString(txt)
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Comment: If I read your question corrcectly, you are searching for a lookahead alternative. You might give `(?:^|[^n]|[^e]n|[^c]en)(ten)` a try.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I want to match "ten" when not preceded by "cen". I have edited the question.

Comment: @SebastianProske That works as expected! Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to the missing support for either lookahead or lookbehind, we need to stick to negated character classes - but `[^c][^e][^n]` doesn't fully cover it, as it would not allow cxxten and also not cover strings where there aren't 3 characters before `ten`.

I came up with `(?:^|[^n]|(?:[^e]|^)n|(?:[^c]|^)en)ten`, that stores `ten` into the first captured group. It's creating alternatives for each possible way to not exactly match `cen`.

An alternative might be matching `(.{0,3})(ten)` and discard the match programatically if the first group stores `cen`.