# Regexp to identify a .gz and NOT a .tar.gz file extension listed in Worker file manager

Tags: regex

I need a simple regexp to identify .gz file extensions but NOT .tar.gz extensions in the Worker file manager.

`.*\.gz$` would identify .gz and .tar.gz which is not what's required.
`.*[^\.]...\.gz$` sort of works.
`.*(?<!\.tar)\.gz` fails as Worker's regexp engine is not that sophisticated and does not seem to support lookarounds. It supports ? and +, and |, () and {} without the need for escaping.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a negative lookahead assertion at the start of your regex pattern, which eliminates the `.tar.gz` extension:

```
^(?!.*\.tar\.gz$).*\.gz$
```

### Demo

Comment: He explained that `Worker's regexp engine is not that sophisticated and does not seem to support lookarounds`

Comment: @Rob The OP only seemed to show that it does not support lookbehinds.  Support for lookaheads are more common.  I will delete if the OP can confirm your statement.

Comment: Thinking of renaming all .tar.gz, .tar.bz2 files to .tgz, .tbz2.

Comment: Update, Worker v4.3.0 help pages refer to 'man 7 regex', so the engine is POSIX.2 compliant. Equivalent to egrep with backward compatibility for old progams such as ed.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Worker's regexp engine is not that sophisticated and does not seem to support lookarounds"*

In that case, maybe the following works for you:

```
^.*(?:[^r]|(?:[^a])r|(?:[^t])ar|(?:[^\.])tar)\.gz$
```

Which would negate any lookaround. Inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38014871/9758194) older post. This should now match any string ending with `.gz`, except strings ending with `.tar.gz`.

But as @TimBiegeleisen [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60338200/9758194). Lookahead support is more common and if available obviously the way to go =)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for all my answers from now @TimBiegeleisen =)

Comment: @w2kpro, any luck with this?

Comment: No, the engine doesn't support non-capture groups. It is similar to the legacy engine used in Gnu Sed.

Answer (score 0):

Worker can use what's called an Extended test. The test uses simple regex as follows:
"name() ~= ".*\.gz$" && ( ( name() ~= ".*\.(tar.gz|tgz)$" ) == false )"
The above statement will find gzip files, but not tar.gz or tgz files.